# React: Change URL without refreshing page in "react-router-dom": "^4.2.2"

Tags: reactjs

I want to change my url's ID dynamically, without page reload, but once i change the URL the page get refreshed and "componentDidMount()" get called everytime.

Here is my code,

```
`handleSelect(selectedIndex) { 
this.props.mediaDetailsProps.history.replace("/post/"+this.props.mediaDetailsProps.match.params.postId+"/media/"+this.props.mediaData[selectedIndex-1].id);

    }`
```

here `this.props.mediaData[selectedIndex-1].id` is my dynamic content, which will change on every handleSelect function call.

**Version used**: 
"react": "^16.6.3",
"react-router-dom": "^4.2.2",

Any help is appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: how have you configured the route

Comment: <Route path="/post/:postId/media/:mediaId" component={(props)=> this.state.userData.isLogin ?
                        ( <MediaDetail propValue={props} userLogout={this.logout}/> )
                       : (<Redirect to='/sign-in' />) } />